# Выпадающая меню на всю ширину

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет.

Есть выпадающая меню на всю ширину экрана .Изначально было  2 панели (`festival` , `media`).Теперь мне надо добавить третий панель выпадающий(`calendar`).

И так как код не я писал мне было очень трудно разобратсья (и код написан  очень криво ) но как то я вник в суть и понял(не польностю).Третий панель я добавил но он не работает так как надо.

И скорее всего (**99%**) проблема тут

```
case 'festival': 
    visiOne = "media";
    break;
case "media":  
    visiOne = 'festival';
    break;  
case 'all':
```

Тут не написано `switch` условие `case` для **calendar**

Даже если я напишу `case "calendar"`  я не знаю какое значение мне дать visiOne (чтобы все работало) так как не очень понимаю именно эту часть кода

Внизу в примере я написал и оставил эту часть так как есть и как вы видите первый и последний блока открываетсья и закрываетсья без проблем но только  у второго есть проблемы (и скорее всего проблема в коде там где я указал).Средний тоже открываетсья и закрываетсья без проблем но если одновременно открыть после него другой блок или открыть его потом другой блок тогда можно увидеть баги.

В **CSS** проблем нету можете туда не смотреть там много кода но проблем там нету это точно.

И если кто нибудь предложит упростить этот код любыми способами буду при много благодарен

Очень прошу помощи.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 "use strict";
 function mineMenu(thisElenent) {
  var visiOne, visiTwo , visiThree;
  var thisHide = thisElenent;
  switch(thisHide) {
   case 'festival': 
    visiOne = "media";
    break;
   case "media":  
    visiOne = 'festival';
    break;

   case 'all': 
    visiOne = 'festival', visiTwo = "media", visiThree = "calendar";
    
    if ($('#'+visiOne).is(":visible")){
     $('#'+visiOne).hide().animate({top: '-400px'}, 500);
    }
    if ($('#'+visiTwo).is(":visible")){
     $('#'+visiTwo).hide().animate({top: '-400px'}, 500);
    }
    if ($('#'+visiThree).is(":visible")){
     $('#'+visiThree).hide().animate({top: '-400px'}, 500);
    }
    $('#menuClose').hide();
    break;
   }
  if ($('#'+visiOne).is(":visible")){
   $('#'+visiOne).hide().animate({top: '-400px'}, 500);
  }
  if ($('#'+visiTwo).is(":visible")){
   $('#'+visiTwo).hide().animate({top: '-400px'}, 500);
  }
  if ($('#'+thisHide).is(":visible")){
   $('#'+thisHide).animate({top: '-400px'}, 500, function(){$('#'+thisHide).hide();});
  }
  else {
   $('#'+thisHide).show().animate({top: '0rem'}, 500);
  }
  return false;
 }
 $('#artistbtn').click(function(){
  mineMenu('festival');
  $('#menuClose').show();
  $(".rotate-art").toggleClass("down"); 
  $(".rotate-media , .rotate-calendar").removeClass("down");
 });
 
 $('#mediabtn').click(function(){
  mineMenu('media');
  $('#menuClose').show();
  $(".rotate-media").toggleClass("down");
  $(".rotate-art , .rotate-calendar").removeClass("down");
 });
 
 $('#calendarbtn').click(function(){
  mineMenu('calendar');
  $('#menuClose').show();
  $(".rotate-calendar").toggleClass("down");
  $(".rotate-art , .rotate-media").removeClass("down");
 });
 $('#menuClose').click(function(){
  mineMenu('all');
  $(".rotate-media, .rotate-art ,rotate-calendar").removeClass("down");
    });
});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 47px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-color: #191919;
  /*Opacity start*/
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -moz-opacity: 0.80;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: 0.8;
  /*Opacity end*/
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3.4px;
  text-align: center;
}
.header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
.header h1 a {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 47px;
  color: #fff;
}
.header h1 a img {
  width: auto;
  height: 47px;
}
.header nav {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5000;
}
.header nav .menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  height: 47px;
  line-height: 3;
}
.header nav .menu .hide .lang-panel {
  display: none;
}
.header nav .menu .hide .lang-panel ul {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.header nav .menu .hide .lang-panel ul li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.header nav .menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.header nav .menu #artistbtn a .fas {
  left: 8%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  color: #c9ac8c;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.header nav .menu #mediabtn {
  position: relative;
}
.header nav .menu #mediabtn a .fas {
  right: 37.5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  color: #c9ac8c;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.header nav .menu #calendar {
  position: relative;
}
.header nav .menu #calendar a .fas {
  right: 37.5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  color: #c9ac8c;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.rotate-art {
  -moz-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -o-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

.rotate-media {
  -moz-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -o-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

.rotate-calendar {
  -moz-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -o-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

.rotate-art.down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.rotate-media.down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.rotate-calendar.down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.subMenu ul {
  display: block;
}

.subMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 168px;
  background-color: #191919;
  /*Opacity start*/
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -moz-opacity: 0.80;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 98;
}
.subMenu ul {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 47px;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 24vw;
}
.subMenu li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 121px;
  height: 71px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 3px #C9AC8C;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.subMenu li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.subMenu li a {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 102%;
  height: 102%;
  margin-top: -1%;
  margin-left: -1%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2.2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #D3D3D3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#menuClose {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 97;
}

#festival,
#calendar,
#media {
  display: none;
  top: -200px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="header" id="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li id="artistbtn"><a href="#">Festival<i class="fas fa-sort-down rotate-art"></i></a></li>
      <li id="calendarbtn"><a href="#">Calendar<i class="fas fa-sort-down rotate-calendar"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
      <li id="mediabtn"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gallery<i class="fas fa-sort-down rotate-media"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>    
</header>
 <!-- submenu dropdown -->
<div class="subMenu" id="festival">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Characters</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Festival Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Volunteers</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="subMenu" id="media">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Characters</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Festival Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Volunteers</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="subMenu" id="calendar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Calendar</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="menuClose"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил добавив эту часть к коду

```
case 'festival': 
    visiOne = 'media'; visiTwo = 'calendar'; visiThree = 'cooper';
    break;
case 'media':  
    visiOne = 'festival'; visiTwo = 'calendar'; visiThree = 'cooper';
    break;

case 'calendar': 
    visiOne = 'festival'; visiTwo = 'media'; visiThree = 'cooper';
    break;

case 'cooper': 
    visiOne = 'festival'; visiTwo = 'calendar'; visiThree = 'media';
    break;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 "use strict";
 function mineMenu(thisElenent) {
  var visiOne, visiTwo , visiThree;
  var thisHide = thisElenent;
  switch(thisHide) {
   case 'festival': 
 visiOne = 'media'; visiTwo = 'calendar'; visiThree = 'cooper';
 break;
case 'media':  
 visiOne = 'festival'; visiTwo = 'calendar'; visiThree = 'cooper';
 break;
 
case 'calendar': 
 visiOne = 'festival'; visiTwo = 'media'; visiThree = 'cooper';
 break;
 
case 'cooper': 
 visiOne = 'festival'; visiTwo = 'calendar'; visiThree = 'media';
 break;

   case 'all': 
    visiOne = 'festival', visiTwo = "media", visiThree = "calendar";
    
    if ($('#'+visiOne).is(":visible")){
     $('#'+visiOne).hide().animate({top: '-400px'}, 500);
    }
    if ($('#'+visiTwo).is(":visible")){
     $('#'+visiTwo).hide().animate({top: '-400px'}, 500);
    }
    if ($('#'+visiThree).is(":visible")){
     $('#'+visiThree).hide().animate({top: '-400px'}, 500);
    }
    $('#menuClose').hide();
    break;
   }
  if ($('#'+visiOne).is(":visible")){
   $('#'+visiOne).hide().animate({top: '-400px'}, 500);
  }
  if ($('#'+visiTwo).is(":visible")){
   $('#'+visiTwo).hide().animate({top: '-400px'}, 500);
  }
  if ($('#'+thisHide).is(":visible")){
   $('#'+thisHide).animate({top: '-400px'}, 500, function(){$('#'+thisHide).hide();});
  }
  else {
   $('#'+thisHide).show().animate({top: '0rem'}, 500);
  }
  return false;
 }
 $('#artistbtn').click(function(){
  mineMenu('festival');
  $('#menuClose').show();
  $(".rotate-art").toggleClass("down"); 
  $(".rotate-media , .rotate-calendar").removeClass("down");
 });
 
 $('#mediabtn').click(function(){
  mineMenu('media');
  $('#menuClose').show();
  $(".rotate-media").toggleClass("down");
  $(".rotate-art , .rotate-calendar").removeClass("down");
 });
 
 $('#calendarbtn').click(function(){
  mineMenu('calendar');
  $('#menuClose').show();
  $(".rotate-calendar").toggleClass("down");
  $(".rotate-art , .rotate-media").removeClass("down");
 });
 $('#menuClose').click(function(){
  mineMenu('all');
  $(".rotate-media, .rotate-art ,rotate-calendar").removeClass("down");
    });
});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 47px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-color: #191919;
  /*Opacity start*/
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -moz-opacity: 0.80;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: 0.8;
  /*Opacity end*/
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3.4px;
  text-align: center;
}
.header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
.header h1 a {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 47px;
  color: #fff;
}
.header h1 a img {
  width: auto;
  height: 47px;
}
.header nav {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5000;
}
.header nav .menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  height: 47px;
  line-height: 3;
}
.header nav .menu .hide .lang-panel {
  display: none;
}
.header nav .menu .hide .lang-panel ul {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.header nav .menu .hide .lang-panel ul li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.header nav .menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.header nav .menu #artistbtn a .fas {
  left: 8%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  color: #c9ac8c;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.header nav .menu #mediabtn {
  position: relative;
}
.header nav .menu #mediabtn a .fas {
  right: 37.5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  color: #c9ac8c;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.header nav .menu #calendar {
  position: relative;
}
.header nav .menu #calendar a .fas {
  right: 37.5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  color: #c9ac8c;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.rotate-art {
  -moz-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -o-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

.rotate-media {
  -moz-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -o-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

.rotate-calendar {
  -moz-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  -o-transition: all, 0.5s, cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

.rotate-art.down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.rotate-media.down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.rotate-calendar.down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.subMenu ul {
  display: block;
}

.subMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 168px;
  background-color: #191919;
  /*Opacity start*/
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -moz-opacity: 0.80;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 98;
}
.subMenu ul {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 47px;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 24vw;
}
.subMenu li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 121px;
  height: 71px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 3px #C9AC8C;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.subMenu li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.subMenu li a {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 102%;
  height: 102%;
  margin-top: -1%;
  margin-left: -1%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2.2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #D3D3D3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#menuClose {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 97;
}

#festival,
#calendar,
#media {
  display: none;
  top: -200px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="header" id="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li id="artistbtn"><a href="#">Festival<i class="fas fa-sort-down rotate-art"></i></a></li>
      <li id="calendarbtn"><a href="#">Calendar<i class="fas fa-sort-down rotate-calendar"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
      <li id="mediabtn"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gallery<i class="fas fa-sort-down rotate-media"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>    
</header>
 <!-- submenu dropdown -->
<div class="subMenu" id="festival">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Characters</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Festival Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Volunteers</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="subMenu" id="media">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Characters</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Festival Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Volunteers</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="subMenu" id="calendar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Calendar</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="menuClose"></div>
```